# mysql insert records challenge

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I have a table that contains topsores of 21 teams. Most of the teams have 5 topscores, but some have 4. For the teams with 4 scores, one needs to be added, being a copy of the worst score. So in the example below for team 1 a copy of record of person 8 must be added (insert) to the table.

Any ideas how to get that done?

Table with:

```
team person score
1       4       13
1       3       9
1       6       8
1       8       4
2       13      12
2       17      8
2       15      7
2       20      7
2       11      6
```

should afterwards have a duplicate record with values 1, 8, 4

Comment: This is an odd thing to do in the database.  Usually it's better to store only "real" data and then perform manipulations of this sort in your presentation layer (if that's all that you're seeking to do); at best this is business logic and belongs in your application code.

Comment: Feel free to answer it as a query preparing output that is not stored. This list needs to be produced however (as a basis for the calculation of a total teamscore including the top-5 scores or in case of a lacking 5th score taking a duplicate of the 4th as a substitute of the 5th score)

Comment: Again, rather than doing that within a query, you could just use the lowest score successive times within your application code if the resultset contains fewer than 5 records for a given team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) together with a query for the [group-wise minimum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
INSERT INTO myTable
  (team, person, score)
SELECT team, person, score FROM myTable NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   team, MIN(score) score
  FROM     myTable
  GROUP BY team
  HAVING   COUNT(*) = 4
) t
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I definitely have to try to understand what the difference is in your query between using NATURAL versus i.e. RIGHT JOIN (which gives an error).

Comment: Slightly off-topic: could you also tell how to add the resulting records to the query output instead of adding it to file?

Comment: @user1837293: `NATURAL JOIN` is shorthand for `INNER JOIN ... USING (all identically named columns)`.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) for a good explanation of the difference between `LEFT`, `RIGHT` and `INNER` joins.

Comment: @user1837293: You could make a `UNION` between the `SELECT` portion of the above command and another `SELECT` of existing records.

Comment: Can you tell how a can use the query without having to repeat the whole query after the two FROM's in your query, since that would make it quite unreadable.

Comment: @user1837293: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.  You could simply do `SELECT team, person, score FROM myTable NATURAL JOIN (SELECT team, MIN(score) score FROM myTable GROUP BY team HAVING COUNT(*) = 4) t UNION ALL SELECT team, person, score FROM myTable`—however, [as I said above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28928874/mysql-insert-records-challenge/28928965?noredirect=1#comment46113712_28928874), you really ought to handle this within your application code rather than in the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72525/discussion-between-user1837293-and-eggyal).